# remove data display in middle of the bar's and every graph from graphs in chart js

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm using  Chart.js v2.9.3 in sails js

my question is how should I remove the values display in the middle of the bars 
config for chat is below

```
var ChartConfig = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Earnings",
      lineTension: 0.3,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 97, 242, 0.05)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0, 97, 242, 1)",
      pointRadius: 3,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 97, 242, 1)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(0, 97, 242, 1)",
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 97, 242, 1)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(0, 97, 242, 1)",
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      data: []
    }]
  },  
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    barValueSpacing: 20,

    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 10,
        right: 25,
        top: 25,
        bottom: 0
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{      
        barThickness: barThickness,
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          padding: 10,
          // maxTicksLimit: 10
        },
        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 10,
          padding: 10,         
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
          zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
          drawBorder: false,
          borderDash: [2],
          zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
        },
        stacked: true,
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        filter: function (item, chart) {
          // Logic to remove a particular legend item goes here
          return !item.text.includes('Emp_Id') && !item.text.includes('Rel_Id')
        }
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
      bodyFontColor: "#858796",
      titleMarginBottom: 10,
      titleFontColor: "#6e707e",
      titleFontSize: 14,
      borderColor: "#dddfeb",
      borderWidth: 1,
      xPadding: 15,
      yPadding: 15,
      displayColors: false,
      intersect: false,
      mode: "index",
      caretPadding: 10,      
    },
    plugins: {
      colorschemes: {
        scheme: ThemeVariable
      },
    },
  }
}
```

also dous not add anything other then this in any place.

the value with a simple bar graph is ok but with stacked bars and pie and doughnut its looks dirty.

I've attached the screenshot of the graph.[graph's spanshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS3PL.png)
can anyone help me with this 
thank you